# How to extract the string in the quotes (either double quotes or single quotes)

Tags: c#, regex

**Question 1:**

For example,

```
     ... "ab'cd" ... 'ab"cd' ...
```

It should get `ab'cd` and `ab"cd` respectively. There may be many quoted strings.

---

**Question 2:**

And how to extract `text <td>...</td> text` from the following string?

```html
<abc>text <td>...</td> text</abc>
<xyz>text <td>...</td> text</xyz>
<def>text <td>...</td> text</def>
```

abc, def, xyz may be nested in `<td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - using back reference.

```
(["'])(?<q>.+?)\1
```

Answer (score 2):

regex:

`(?:"(?<text>[^"]*)")|(?:'(?<text>[^']*)')`

and the whole snippet:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(
@"(?:""(?<text>[^""]*)"")|(?:'(?<text>[^']*)')",
RegexOptions.None
);
```

Testable on [my blog](http://blog.stevekonves.com/2012/01/an-even-better-regex-tester/) (requires silverlight)

Comment: Is it a way to avoid to write `(?<text>[^"]*)` twice? It can be a very long complex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a 2-in-1 question right?

My answer to 1 is

```
((.*)['"](.*))
```

then for #2

```
<(abc|xyz|def)>(.*)<\/(abc|xyz|def)>
```

abc | xyz | def <- imagine it like this

dont forget to TRIM the spaces before you use the results

Comment: The second solution will match `<abc>...</xyz>`, which is not well formed.

Comment: yeah, its a bit not wellformed, but it depends on how your data will come to you.

You could do it like this if you want,
(<abc>(.*)<\/abc>)|(<xyz>(.*)<\/xyz>)|(<def>(.*)<\/def>)

Answer (score 0):

for **first** question use:

`("(?<content>[^"]*)")|('(?<content>[^']*)')`

for **second** question:

`>(?<content>\w*\s*<td>.*</td>[\w\s]*)<`

and get group named *content* for both.