# Extracting strings in Python in either single or double quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, quotes, findall

I need help with a Python regex to extract strings either inside single or double quoted. I found a solution but the regex is in C# here:

[How to extract the string in the quotes (either double quotes or single quotes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369261/how-to-extract-the-string-in-the-quotes-either-double-quotes-or-single-quotes)

I need to parse this string

```
tags = { 'one' : "two", "three", 'four' }
```

and return the array items:

```
one
two
three
four
```

Currently I have this for single quotes:

```
quoted = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", buffer, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> buffer="tags = { 'one' : \"two\", \"three\", 'four' }"
>>> re.findall(r"['\"](.*?)['\"]", buffer)
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! Is there any way I can return what quote was used on each item?

Comment: @Ron Saying `re.findall(r"(['\"])(.*?)['\"]", buffer)` would give you a list of tuples.

Comment: This will fail if a value contains an escaped quote, or a quote of the other kind, though. The latter you can fix by using a backref for the closing quote, like `(['\"])(.*?)\1`.