# Extract single and double quoted strings

Tags: php, regex

This question is basically the same as [How to extract the string in the quotes (either double quotes or single quotes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11369261/1369417), except in PHP.

Basically, I want a function like this:

```
function extract_tokens($text) {
    preg_match_all('/Foo\((?:\'(?<text>.*?)\'|"(?<text>.*?)")\)/', $text, $matches);
    return $matches['text'];
}
```

However, this is not allowed in PHP: `PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same name`.

My current solution seems overly complicated for a simple goal:

```
function extract_tokens($text) {
    preg_match_all('/Foo\((\'(.*?)\'|"(.*?)")\)/', $text, $matches);
    return array_map(function($token) {
        return substr($token, 1, strlen($token) - 2);
    }, $matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function extract_tokens($text) {
    preg_match_all('/Foo\(([\'"])(?<text>.*?)\1\)/', $text, $matches);
    return $matches['text'];
}
```